# Is there a mind probe lying around in the middle of this Death Star meeting room?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope, death-star

[image: Death Star Meeting]

There's a large, shiny black thing sitting in the middle of the table during this imperial meeting on the Death Star during *A New Hope*. It bears a striking resemblance to the [mind probe](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/IT-O_Interrogator) that the Empire uses to torture Princess Leia later in the movie. I realise that there were probably plenty of black, shiny things in the Death Star in its heyday but to my mind it looks like an IT-O Interrogator. Can anyone confirm what this object actually is? And, if it is a mind probe, why is it lying around on the middle of an office table?

Comment: Logic says it's likely some kind of communications device, but I don't know enough about SW to say what exactly it is. Reuse of a prop wouldn't be that surprising though.

Comment: It's a conference phone. The reason you don't see it in use in that scene? Nobody can find the IT contractor's instructions for setting up a call, and Palpatine always forgets to press # to join the meeting anyway.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The Star Wars Encyclopedia identifies it as a "**[holoprojector](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Death_Star_conference_room)**"

[image]

This ties in nicely with the decription of the room in the [Visual Dictionary](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Visual_Dictionary)

[image]

Interestingly, the official Star Wars CCG (Collectible Card Game) refers to it as a "Holo**table**"

[image]

Comment: @TheDarkLord - I want you to say "*I'm sorry, but this answer is lacking sources*" so I can reply with "*I find your lack of faith disturbing*"

Comment: He's not accepted the answer. I think he's waving his hand going "These aren't the sources I'm looking for"

Comment: "The source is strong with this one..."